# datagridview cancelrowedit event for existing rows in datasource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview bound to a bindingsource (which is bound to a dataview). Virtual mode is on.

I am trying to catch any row edit cancel (esc key) that occurs in the grid so I can log it.

My testing shows that when a new row is added to the datagridview but uncommitted to the datasource I can catch this event. For any existing rows in the datasource this event is not raised.

Is there another event I need to use for the existing rows? Or do I need to do something other than turn on virtual mode in my grid?

Answer (score 0):

try this it will can help you.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cancelrowedit(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cancelrowedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

I am trying to do some similar like you do so I found this information. It did help me.
Regards,

Comment: It might be useful to also include that code snippet in your answer, that way, if the content of that link changes (or is taken offline) your answer is still helpful.

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue though. The event is never raised for an existing row when the escape key is pressed. Only when it is a new uncommitted row does the event raise.